# SNI and HTTP hostname mismatch

Tags: php, curl, openssl, apache2

I have one web application that uses CURL to talk to other web applications on the same server. All of the applications share a domain but have different subdomains. They share a wildcard SSL certificate. I am getting these errors in my error log:

```
Hostname c.my.app provided via SNI and hostname b.my.app provided via HTTP are different
```

When `a.my.app` is using cURL to communicate with `b.my.app`. It appears that SNI is getting a "random" hostname instead of using it based on the hostname. I don't understand what is going on.

Is there an easy way to fix this? Or is there a way to disable this check?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code you use for doing the requests.